# How to check if the session is expired in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i couldn't handle the session expired check in MVC 3,
Initially i have tried MVC filter(Action Executing) to check the session, but i couldn't accesses the request.session variable in side the action filter,

And i tried using session_Start method in global.asax, but the problem is when the session is expired it will not go to sesion_start method

Answer (score 0):

You can create attribute some thing like this

```
public class SessionExpireFilterAttribute:ActionFilterAttribute 
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting( ActionExecutingContext filterContext ) {
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

       //  check if session is supported
        if(ctx.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {


            if (ctx.Session != null)
            {

                // check if a new session id was generated
                if (ctx.Session.IsNewSession)
                {

                    // If it says it is a new session, but an existing cookie exists, then it must
                    // have timed out
                    string sessionCookie = ctx.Request.Headers["Cookie"];
                    if (null == sessionCookie)
                    {
                        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

                        const string loginUrl = @"~/Login/Login";
                        var rr = new RedirectResult(loginUrl);
                        filterContext.Result = rr;


                    }
                    if ((null != sessionCookie) && (sessionCookie.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") <= 0))
                    {
                        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                        const string loginUrl = @"~/Login/Login";
                        var rr = new RedirectResult(loginUrl);
                        filterContext.Result = rr;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {

            ctx.Response.Redirect(@"~/Login/Login");
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting ( filterContext );
    }
}
```